# On a keyboard layout where caret (^) is a combining key, how do I make it not combing without using the spacebar?

Tags: keyboard

On my keyboard layout, the caret is one of the *dead keys*, a combining diacritical mark that one has to combine with a second key.  e.g. to produce `ê` I type <kbd>^</kbd><kbd>e</kbd>. To type `^` I need to type <kbd>^</kbd> <kbd>spacebar</kbd>. This is the default behaviour.

However, if I want to type `^b`, I need to type three things, <kbd>^</kbd> <kbd>spacebar</kbd> <kbd>b</kbd>. 
<kbd>^</kbd> <kbd>b</kbd> results in nothing, because there is no combination of that combining diacritical character with the letter `b`.

Is it however possible to configure Ubuntu that it acts as some other systems do: <kbd>^</kbd> <kbd>b</kbd> results in `^b` instead of no character at all?  In other words: If the second character following a dead key does not have a combination with that combining diacritical character, the result is the dead key "symbol" (in more Unicode terms: the spacing, non-combining, alternative to the combining diacritical mark) plus the 2nd letter, instead of nothing.

## Background

- https://superuser.com/questions/727050/
- [Some characters like quotes only appear after pressing spacebar, how to change this?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/68051/)
- [How can I use dead keys for consonants?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/110828/)
- https://superuser.com/questions/122625/

Comment: I don't know if I'm missing something, but why not use Shift+6 to get ^?

Comment: Could you add what kind of keyboard layout you have? Maybe you could post a photography of it? Also what does `you need ++` mean in your description?

Comment: That was the result of bad markup.  I've edited the question to fix it, and to explain the part that Mitch missed.

Comment: I live in Belgium, so I'm on a azerty keyboard (https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/AZERTY), moreover on a MacBook so it is https://support.apple.com/library/content/dam/edam/applecare/images/en_US/keyboards/french_notebook.png